# Error "Expected String or Bytes-like object, got int" during the errorlog open

Tags: installation, permission-denied, mysql-8.0, ubuntu-22.04, error-log

I'm tring to configurate mysql 8 on Ubuntu 22.04, and when I open the error log using the mysql workbench adminsitrations, i'm geting the messages "Error creating log reader: Name 'operationCancelledErros' is not defined" and a popup error whit message: "Expected string or byte-likeobject, got 'int'" [Error message from mysql workbench, trying to access the errorlog by administrations tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vquuu.png).

This error beguns after I changed the permission of /var/log/mysql folder to 755 and the group/owner from mysql:adm to mysql:mysql. I was geting the error "permission denied" to open log errors in mysql workbench.

Iam trying to finish the configurations of mysql 8, after the instalattion, but can not access external files on load data and I was looking for the error log registers to solve this problem.

```
[mysqld]

user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port                    = 3306
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql

Mysqld.cnf:

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
#mysqlx-bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
key_buffer_size         = 16M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/query.log
general_log             = 1
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

secure-file-priv        = ""
local-infile = 1

skip-log-bin
# -------------------------------------------
```

[Mysql "/var/log/mysql", actual permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTkxf.png)